# Insert Values select PHP

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO grade7 (studentid,section) VALUES (SELECT MAX(studentid)  FROM student_profile limit 1), '----';
```

What is wrong with my code, tried it individually it works

Comment: If you are using this exact query then where is your last brace?  INSERT INTO grade7 (studentid,section) VALUES (SELECT MAX(studentid)  FROM student_profile limit 1), '----' `)`;

Comment: Use this `INSERT INTO grade7 (studentid,section) VALUES (SELECT MAX(studentid)  FROM student_profile limit 1, '----');`

Comment: It expect 2 parameters to be filled but you just specify 1.

Comment: still wont work dude

Comment: @chris85 Maybe he tried the subquery separately and it ran.

Comment: @JONASVINCENTSamson, what is not working?

Comment: i want to take the student id from student_profile which have auto increment , newbie here sorry

Comment: @JONASVINCENTSamson Tim's answer below doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with using a subquery as the predicate of `VALUES` during an insert.  More typical would be to use `INSERT INTO grade7 ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO grade7 (studentid, section)
SELECT MAX(studentid), '----'
FROM student_profile
```

If you are doing this work directly on MySQL, then you might also be able to use MySQL's [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function, which returns the auto increment value from the most recent insert.  If you had just done the insert on `student_profile`, then you could have simply used this to insert into `grade7`:

```
INSERT INTO grade7 (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '----')
```

Comment: Thanks Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery needs a pair of parentheses, but your `VALUES` *also* needs parentheses.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO grade7 (studentid,section)
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(studentid) FROM student_profile limit 1), '----');
```

Comment: You’re welcome. Would you care to accept this answer?